# How to get and save data of the nearest element in page in python django

Tags: python, django, forms

I need to add comment module on my homepage in django python - simple textarea under each post. I need to get the nearest post id before i save it in my form, that my comment knows to which post is related.

My forms.py

```py
class newPost(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ['author', 'date_posted']
        fields = ('content', 'date_posted', 'author')

class newComment(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        exclude = ['author', 'date', 'post']
        fields = ('content', 'date', 'author', 'post')
```

My views.py

```py
def home(request):
    newPostForm = newPost()
    newCommentForm = newComment()
    if request.is_ajax():
        newPostForm = newPost(request.POST)
        newCommentForm = newComment(request.POST)
        if newPostForm.is_valid():
            instance = newPostForm.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.date_posted = timezone.now()
            instance.save()
            data = {
                'message': 'post is added'
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)
        if newCommentForm.is_valid():
            instance = newCommentForm.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.date = timezone.now()
            instance.save()
            data = {
                'message': 'comment is added'
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)
    context = {
        'newPostForm': newPostForm,
        'newCommentForm': newCommentForm,
        'posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted'),
        'comments': Comment.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')
    }
```

and my home.html

```html
 <div class="leftcolumn">
            <div class="new_post_form">
                <form METHOD="POST" class="new_post" id="new_post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ newPostForm }}
                    <button type="submit">Publish</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="posts">
            {% for post in posts %}
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="user" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>, {{ post.date_posted }}
                    <img src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" alt="{{ post.author }}" style="width:100%;">
                    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
                    {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
                    <div class="comment">
                        <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
                        <form METHOD="POST" class="new_comment" id="new_commentt">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ newCommentForm }}
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
            </div>
```

I don't know even what to begins... I'm thinking about javascript that put this post id in request, but I don't know how. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

trun this instruction : if `request.is_ajax():` to `if request.method == 'POST':`

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your views to handle each case as a good practice. Have a look at [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView). Then you can build a url where you can pass the post id in the path

Comment: I don't want to go to another page, so building url with post id won't do anything to me :/

Comment: You don't need to go to another page to create a view, it can just return the same JsonResponse

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a just edited my views.py and now it looks like:

```py
@login_required()
def home(request):
    newPostForm = newPost()
    newCommentForm = newComment()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'newPostSubmit' in request.POST:
            newPostForm = newPost(request.POST, prefix='newpost')
            if newPostForm.is_valid():
                instance = newPostForm.save(commit=False)
                instance.author = request.user
                instance.date_posted = timezone.now()
                instance.save()
            newCommentForm = newComment(prefix='newcomment')
        elif 'newCommentSubmit' in request.POST:
            newCommentForm = newComment(request.POST, prefix='newcomment')
            if newCommentForm.is_valid():
                instance = newCommentForm.save(commit=False)
                instance.author = request.user
                instance.date_posted = timezone.now()
                instance.save()
            newPostForm = newPost(prefix='newpost')
    else:
        newPostForm = newPost(prefix='newpost')
        newCommentForm = newComment(prefix='newcomment')
    context = {
        'newPostForm': newPostForm,
        'newCommentForm': newCommentForm,
        'posts': Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted'),
        'comments': Comment.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

Still don't know how to relate post to comment, how to get my `{{ post.id }}` value and push it to my post field. I tryied also this on but still not working:

```html
<form METHOD="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="{{ newCommentForm.content }}">
<input type="hidden" value="{{ post.id }}" name="{{ newCommentForm.post }}">
<button type="submit" name="newCommentSubmit">Add</button>
</form>
```